# How "relevant" is the non-thread-safety of XmlWriterTraceListener?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, trace

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx XmlWriterTraceListener is not thread-safe. (I know that Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener is, but I think that XmlWriterTraceListener format is much more readable using Microsoft Service Trace Viewer).

However, I "only" use it for a desktop application with the UI thread and a maximum of 2 BackgroundWorkers using the XmlWriterTraceListener as a <s>Source</s> Listener at the same time. 
How "relevant" is the non-thread-safety in this case, considering performance impact?
Tracing messages are written relatively scarely, i.e. not every second.

edit:
The UI thread and the Background worker(s) use different TraceSources (each creates their own).
The TraceListener (at the moment FileLogTraceListener, as I was unsure about thread-safety) is a static public property in the App class. I add it to the TraceSources in the constructors of the classes owning the TraceSource.

Comment: "Scarely" never has anything to do with thread safety.  It just makes the bugs much harder to diagnose.  No, it is not thread safe and you *must* use a lock to prevent more than one thread making a call at the same time.

Comment: How relevant? Well, as relevant as you want to make it. Even though the writes occur "not every second", there is still a chance of two threads trying to write at the exact same time. The result of it will be either a non-event, or application failure, depending on your particular implementation. Without additional details, it is hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. Explained a bit more in the question.
So to make it thread-safe, I would have to / could create a wrapper class which locks the listener during the Trace* method calls?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. The `Trace` class is thread-safe by default if the underlying listener(s) isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Trace` class has a property, [UseGlobalLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.usegloballock(v=vs.110).aspx) which should be `true` if the underlying listener(s) report that they're not thread-safe.

In other words, if you're using a trace listener that isn't thread-safe with the `Debug` or `Trace` class, then those classes (`Trace`/`Debug`) will make sure the underlying listener is handled in a thread-safe manner.

In other words, your question about how relevant the missing thread safety is for the trace listener, then the answer is *not very*. It might be relevant from a performance standpoint, if you create a listener there might be some minor performance to gain by making the listener thread-safe, if this can be handled in a different manner than just a global lock around it.

If you're unsure you can force this property to be `true`, and the documentation has an example for how to do that here, [Trace.UseGlobalLock Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.usegloballock(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace useGlobalLock="false" />
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Note that if you're using the trace listener object with something other than the `Trace` class, then this answer is not applicable.

Note that the `Debug` class is using the same underlying framework as the `Trace` class, but does not have the property.

The current implementation of `Debug` and `Trace` is that they both wrap an internal static class, and thus if you add a debug listener it gets added to trace and vice versa. As such, the property `Trace.UseGlobalLock` is applicable for `Debug.WriteXYZ` as well.

Comment: Regarding "... if you're using the trace listener object with something other than the Trace class ...":
If I understand that correctly, it means the global lock won't apply if I access the listener directly (calling `listener.Write(text)` for example from my code).
I'm using the trace listener through my created `TraceSource`s. Does the GlobalLock apply to them?

Comment: TraceSource ends up checking the global lock property, so apparently, yes, but I'm not sure I can read that out of the documentation. Might be undocumented behavior.